# Build failed : Expected identifier error

Tags: objective-c

Hi i am trying to learn Objective C , i try to write code which is same as tutorial but i couldn't run the program.

It says Expected identifier for  `NSAutoreleasePool * pool= [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]];`
what is missing in my code ?

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface Person : NSObject
    {
        int age;
        int weight;
    }
    -(void) print;
    -(void) setAge : (int) a;
    -(void) setWeight : (int) w;
    @end

    @implementation Person

    -(void) print{

        NSLog(@"His name is %i and his weight is %i" , age, weight);

    }
    -(void) setAge:(int)a {
        age = a;

    }
    -(void) setWeight:(int)w {
        weight=w;

    }

    @end

    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {

        NSAutoreleasePool * pool= [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]];
        Person *person;

        person = [Person alloc];
        person = [person init];

        [person  setAge : 24];
        [person setWeight:90];

        [person print];
        [person release];
        [pool drain];
        return  0;
}


}
```

Comment: Alloc and init is always a nested call - do never separate. This should be one of the first things to learn (ie always do `[[object alloc] init];` this goes also for your person object of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a message in your outer set of brackets.  Change to:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool= [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
```